# Unable to load the requested file: helpers/form_helper.php

Tags: forms, codeigniter, helper

when I run in localhost, my application running well but when I upload to web server, there is a sentence below:

> Unable to load the requested file: helpers/form_helper.php

what is the major problem with this error?

Comment: Not nearly enough details. This could be thousands of things, But I'm assuming your file is in the wrong location/named wrong.

Comment: May be you have not included the form helper but used its methods in one of the controller.Are you getting this error on a particular page?

Comment: this may be naming convention problem. you file name may be form_helper.php and it is expecting Form_helper.php on server

Answer (score 1):

if you use windows system to run localhost as development enviorment,
and if there are some upper-case characters for the file or folder name,  than upload to Linux web server, that problem could happen, because Linux is case-Sensitive， so change all the file and folder name to lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

just lowercase the filenames inside helpers folder 
and replace the name of the file `form_helper in autoload['form_helper']`

Answer (score 0):

3 Steps To Solve The Problem

1. Check your file name in application\helpers (complete name should be in small letters)
2. Controler in which you are loading should be in small letters
3. Have a Cup of Coffee because you have done it!

> $this->load->helper('form_helper');
>
> application\helpers\form_helper.php
> visit [Codeigniter Official](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/helpers.html) for more deIail
> i have just [implimented on a website](https://www.kitsoul.com)